# A Job in Data Science - What can I do if I can't meet target goals?

Tags: software-development

I've started a new job in data science a few months back. The problem I was assigned to was very challenging, but exciting. Our client was using a very simple baseline model to make predictions, and wanted to improve on it by employing more sophisticated machine learning methods, and that's where me and my team came in.

The very simple baseline algorithm works pretty well. After much experimentation and research, I could only beat the baseline by around 20%, when our goal was to beat it by twice as much. At the start of the project, I was already very nervous about the target performance that we were aiming for. In research, we never made guarantees about how well the model will perform on the data (we could only hypothesize); it was a matter of implementing it and finding out. My boss seems extremely dissatisfied with these results, but I'm at loss with how to bring the error down further.

I do acknowledge that I may be in need of further training, and that I still have so much to learn. I've also read articles like [this](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/always-start-with-a-stupid-model-no-exceptions-3a22314b9aaa) and [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/first-create-a-common-sense-baseline-e66dbf8a8a47) specifying that sometimes, simple baseline models are better than complex methods. However, I still can't help but feel like a failure for not being able to reach our target performance.

Does this mean I am under performing as a data scientist if I can't beat the baseline by a large margin? Or is this a usual experience (for those who've been in a the field for quite some time)? How can I communicate that the target performance is unattainable?

Comment: The only way anyone could even hint that you are underperforming is if another data scientist were somehow able to extract better predictions from the same data. - Just because someone pulled "100% improvement" out of his sphincter before you even approached the problem is no reason for you to take that as a goal.

Comment: I wish I can help, it sounds to me that this is an off-topic OP for this site because your Q as is not is opinion-based.

Answer (score 4):

Please ask yourself and your senior data scientists if the target performance is reasonable or not. For example, it's not reasonable to expect a 100% accuracy for the simple MINST data set.

Assume the target performance is reasonable and your boss wants that to happen. Generally, you have the following options:

- Please **study** the failing cases. You shouldn't treat machine learning as a black box, you should take a look at the cases where model fail. There might be a pattern that you can further extract.
- Re-engineering your feature sets. Kaggle people have good examples, please take a look. Does your data set look good?
- Check your overfitting. You need good crossvalidation for bringing your error rates down.
- Try several models. GBM, SVM, neural networks etc. Data scientists generally need to understand quite a number of mathematical models.

Your experience is **not unusual**. Many people have had this experience, it's quite common. If you take note at the Kaggle prize winners, they would spend months just on improving error rate by something 2%. The non-winners could spend even more time on no improvement gain.

If your existing model is already good, it's not simple to improve it even further. For example, deep learning might not improve the performance much if the data can be linearly separable. You're not alone.

Answer (score -1):

I will reformulate the question into something more general:

Does an expectation onto the first task for an beginner which is not matched make him bad in his job? No, I would not draw such a conclusion from this observation.

- It could be that the expectation was to high (in this case: it could be that the baseline model matches the underlying model.)
- It could be that the problem is poorly understood. E.g. I am doing a very special application of data based optimization and it took me (Physics Phd) and my very experienced Colleague (Mathematics Phd) several months to analyze the problem to a depth that we could reasonably start
- It could be that the problem is plainly complex - new people who start with me/my colleague currently take several months until they understand the underlying logics/abstract goals of what we do.